# Would an AJAX script persist a session in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, session

I've been asked to develop a social networking site to tie in with a game. The game is in Flash (so delivered as just a `.swf` file) and will be hosted on the social networking website.

One of the issues that's arisen during testing and developing is sessions timing out. I know session length can (theoretically) be modified using `php.ini` but in this instance it doesn't seem to have worked, most likely due to restrictions by our hosting provider.

Sessions are timing out because the game opens in a pop-up window, and if visitors remain on the game window for a long period of time, close the window and then attempt to use the social networking website, the next page load prompts them to log in.

Therefore, if I dropped a small JavaScript snippet into the head of my pages that simply fires off a request to a file hosted on the website, will that persist a session? If so, are there any drawbacks to this practice?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, chaps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes Martin this does work. Javascript has access to the same cookies that your PHP session does. This means on your page that you do session_start(); on and start interacting with $_SESSION  if an AJAX page makes a request to this page then they share the same cookies, thus both share the same $_SESSION.

Page 1 - Page receiving the AJAX request

```
session_start();
die(isset($_SESSION['myvar']) ? 'it exists' : 'it does not exist');
```

Page 2 - Page making the AJAX request

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['myvar'] = 1;
```

When you access page 2, session starts and sets a session variable 'myvar'. If you make an AJAX request from Page 2 to Page 1, then Page 1 has the variable 'myvar' set in the session and thus the output would be 'it exists'.

Hope this helps demystify sessions a little bit for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the requested script calls session_start(), then the session cookie should be renewed on each request. At first glance I can't see why it would not work.